# SQL Server Denormalize Table and Still Link to a Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, lookup-tables, denormalization

I have 2 tables & 1 lookup table:

tbl 1 (this houses a persons info from a survey):

```
CREATE TABLE SurveyCustomerInfoTbl (
  [SurveyID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Age] int NOT NULL,
  [Gender] int NOT NULL,
  [Race] int NOT NULL,
  [County] int NOT NULL,
  [SurvType] varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  [ProvID] varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  [EnterDate] [datetime] NULL,
  [UserName] varchar(200) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SurveyCustomerInfoTbl ] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[SurveyID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SurveyCustomerInfoTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_SurveyCustomerInfoTbl _EnterDate] 
DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [EnterDate]
GO

INSERT INTO SurveyCustomerInfoTbl ([SurveyID], [Age], 
[Gender], [Race], [County], [SurvType], [ProvID], [EnterDate], [UserName]) VALUES
  ('1', '11', '2', '1', '59', 'Adult', '12-1234567', '20130515',  'Jwhite'),
  ('2', '8', '2', '1', '59', 'Child', '12-1234567', '20130515', 'Jwhite'),
  ('3', '15', '2', '1', '59', 'Adult', '12-1234567', 2013-05-15, 'Jwhite'),
  ('4', '12', '2', '1', '59', 'Child', '12-1234567', '20130515', 'Jwhite');
```

tbl 2 (this houses answers to questions from a survey):

```
CREATE TABLE SurveyCustomerAnswersTbl (
  [SurveyAnswerID] bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [SurveyID] bigint NOT NULL,
  [QuestionID] int NOT NULL,
  [Answer] int NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SurveyCustomerAnswersTbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[SurveyAnswerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SurveyCustomerAnswersTbl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_SurveyCustomerAnswersTbl_SurveyCustomerInfoTbl] FOREIGN KEY([SurveyID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SurveyCustomerInfoTbl] ([SurveyID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SurveyCustomerAnswersTbl] CHECK CONSTRAINT
[FK_SurveyCustomerAnswersTbl_SurveyCustomerInfoTbl]
GO

INSERT INTO SurveyCustomerAnswersTbl ([SurveyID], [QuestionID], [Answer]) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '4'),
  ('1', '2', '4'),
  ('1', '3', '5'),
  ('1', '4', '4'),
  ('2', '1', '2'),
  ('2', '2', '3')
```

Lookup Tbl (this maps sets of questions as sections):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[lkpSectionQuestion](
    [SectionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SurvType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_lkpSectionQuestion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[SectionID] ASC,
[QuestionID] ASC,
[SurvType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


INSERT INTO lkpSectionQuestion 
([SectionID], [QuestionID], [SurvType])
VALUES
 (1, 1, Adult),
 (1, 1, Child),
 (1, 2, Adult),
 (1, 2, Child),
 (..,..,..),
```

I have then combined & denormalized the personinfo tbl & answertbl into 1, to try and remove a few steps when importing to tables.

ex: all q1 answers are in 1 column:
SurveyID | Age | Gender | Race | .... | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | ...

What I am trying to figure out is, if I do this, can I still link questions&answers to a SectionID, for reporting purposes. 
ex: "Q1" & "Q2" are both considered part of "section 1" of the survey. So when I run a report such as "total questions answered by sections"

Comment: Start by defining your proposed primary keys. In addition, we don't know what your model actually represents. Your table names are not particularly clear while you do clearly indicate that you have "denormalized" (but from what properly normalized model we don't know) which clouds understanding. I can say this - your quest to "make it easy" is typically a path that will lead to continuous pain trying to make effective and efficient use of the data you import. And your attempt to make "sections" has no clear definition or purpose. More detail is needed.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the PK and FK to the post. Updated and I clarified a bit more on what I use sections for.

Comment: In general, yes you can always link normalised tables to a de-normalised one. You must make sure that your de-normalised table contains all the necessary keys to link to lookup tables. I am wondering if `SurveyCustomerAnswersTbl ` is missing `[SurvType]` column, as it appears to be part of Survey PK.

Comment: Frankly, `ex: all q1 answers are in 1 column:.....` onward is not clear.do you mean you have concatenated multiple column to one column and store in database.It is not clear.better show table and you query.If you store both person info like Name, Age etc in both table then that is not proper way of denormalizing.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I wanted to do. I finished de-normalizing my table, and then I 
explicitly wrote keys and values in my queries, views etc. I basically wanted to combine to steps into one. Instead of inserting my data into two final tables, I just insert into one. Also queries are simpler/faster, as I got rid of almost all of the joins in my queries.